# chrome.notifications.create is not working inside callback function

Tags: google-chrome-extension

popup.js

```
function start(){
let options = {
    type: "basic",
    title: "Primary Title",
    message: "Primary message to display",
    iconUrl: "/icon_128.png"
}

chrome.notifications.create(options);
}

    // When the button is clicked, inject function will execute on current page
    startButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
        let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
    
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            target: { tabId: tab.id },
            function: start,
        });
    });
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Meet Auto Exit Bot",
    "description": "Exits meet based on number of people present.",
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon_128.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "storage",
        "activeTab",
        "scripting",
        "notifications"
    ]
```

}

I am developing a chrome in which I am using chrome notifications to notify users. But I am not able to figure out why `chrome.notifications.create` is not working inside my `start()` function. It works when using outside the callback function.

Comment: What's the error on console?

Comment: @Robbi its not showing error

Comment: When I put same code outside the start() function it works

Comment: 1. Are you checking the popup devTool console or you've opened the service worker console?   2. Try to embed background script in a try catch statement (if you have not already done)

Comment: Getting this error in console `ReferenceError: Image is not defined`

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/S67zHbK/Capture.jpg

Comment: This error is due to a known bug alterady solved first in Chome Dev and Canary channel. What the version of your chrome\chromium browser ?

Comment: Version 90.0.4430.93 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: In any case you don't have to create a notification in a injected content script. Create it in the popup or background script.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232289/discussion-between-harshith-va-and-robbi).

Comment: The bug is fixed in Chrome 91, https://crbug.com/1168477, so use MV2 until it becomes stable.